# Change XML color programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Is it possible to change XML colors via Kotlin/java code.
There's only 5 colors in my app, and in the settings you can change the theme. I don't want to change each element to the new color, but I want to change the XML color so all the elements get the new colors.
For example:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#6c6c6c</color>
```

I want to change it whenever a switch element is `ON` to

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>
```

The main Idea is I want all the elements to get their colors from a source.

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot modify the values of resources at runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of a group of elements at once?
Or if you know how to change a whole theme of an app without selecting and changing the color of the elements manually.

Comment: You have to use app themes for that. Create a new theme and change it programmatically. See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Comment: Thank you so much @LucasDeMoraisCabrales that was very helpful. Can you post an answer so I can mark is as useful?

Comment: Alright glad I could help, that's done

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change XML resource values at runtime as @CommonsWare commented.

In order to change all colors dinamically, the best way is to use app themes for that. Create a new theme and change it programmatically.

See: [Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)