# How to change programmatically an android xml color value with a selector

Tags: android

I wanted to create a `@color/` color value **that can be changed programmatically**, but I don't know how to do.
Here is my code (color/color_account.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/colorId" android:color="#"/>
</selector>
```

But the id isn't accepted and I can't use it as a drawable (logical).
Can someone explain me how to do?
The colors are not defined, they are chosen by the users so it must be changed programmatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change pressed color to other color of selector dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273545/how-to-change-pressed-color-to-other-color-of-selector-dynamically)

Comment: No, I want a personnalised theme, not a changed color with an event. I must be able to change all the views with the default color by the user color. Sorry if I'm not very clear

Comment: Finally I change all the text colors and the shape solid color too, but if it is a better way I'm always interested. If there is vars in css, why not in xml styles?

Comment: Ok it doesn't works, sorry, my shape color isn't modifiable because it is in a selector with another shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm getting your question right you want to change a color in `colors.xml` programmatically. And sadly because all the colors in that file are static final ints you can not change them. You can either set new resource value in there or set a color out of your `colors.xml` with code.

Comment: But can I change a color outside colors.xml but always named @color/colorAccount?

Comment: when u say @color it is referring to colors.xml on your project so it is impossible to change a value of it if its in annotation of color or have separated values with same names. if your gonna change the colors with the users choice i recommend to do that with color picker. either making it yourself or use the color picker libraries. then initialize any view you are going to change color with and set the whatever color of that view to the selected color by the user.

Comment: also the idea of using theme for handling the color of views in general is ofcourse a good idea but there are some needs that make some one to use a color picker or just changing some views colors without themes that is up to you to decide which one you want

Comment: But a color picker is an input, it isn't? I just have to change an @color/colorId value to change the whole color of the application theme, but to chose the color it is already possible, no need about that

Comment: I get what you're saying but the point is that you don't get the permission to change the value of a "@color " cause there is no way to do that. the only way is finding a way to set a color with or without making a new "@color" value either with or without color picker.the color picker is a view to help you to take a color by your user's choice and do whatever you want to do with it but remember you don't have any possible way to change value of an already made color value.

Comment: Is there variables who can be used by @color values (per example <color name="colorId">@vars/colorAccount</color>)?

Comment: yes you can get color values in many ways. one of the ways is to call a method `getResources().getColor(R.colors.colorname)` then you can store this value to a variable type of Color. or even for your information you can use the Color class to have colors out of colors value you saved, for example `Color.GREY` gives you an integer of gray color that you can use anywhere you want.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to set the value of a @color/color with a variable (@vars/color per example) without changing exactly the color (because this isn't possible)? I can't change the color of a shape into a drawable selector (I don't find how) so my last chance is to change directly the @color/colorPrimary (between others) so I have to set a color. If it isn't possible to change the color value can I make it depending of another value?

Comment: I'm not sure that i get you right but if you are asking that you can set a value of a color in colors.xml with a variable out of that xml the answer is no because it's in opposite meaning of the final int. when you say final int or generally final variable you must set the value directly in that specific moment.and of course if you dont see a problem you can say more about your views that has the shape and you want it to change color and i can help you more on that too.If you think i didnt get your meaning don't mind to explain more to me so i can help you the best i can.

Comment: Ok. Does it change with the selectors (/res/colors/color_account.xml with an id)? Or there is really no way to do it (perhaps if I create again each shapes with each selected statements and each attributes?)

Comment: its totally impossible for that to happen

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file named colors.xml in res/values and add your color codes in that xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="mycolor">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Now when you want to use that color you can do `@color/mycolor`

Comment: Sorry but I want to change this color with a personnalised another color, so I can't use this method

Comment: In this case, you can try using themes. This post has the similar problem, maybe it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136548/change-xml-color-programmatically/50136813

Comment: I read, but I don't find how to change a color programmatically (sorry if I'm repeating). It explain how to change the color with another defined color, but mine must be chosen by the user, and I will not write the 16777216 colors existing, so I must change an attribute of a @color/colorAccount with an id or something like that

Comment: Well since you want user the choose color while program is running, you can get color code with a color picker used by the user. And change the color of element you want to change. But either way, if user chooses the color from xml or from color picker, you have to save the colorcode so you can use it later. If so, why not just save the colorcode without xml? It might not the answer you're looking for but this is best i can think of. Sorry for cant helping you more. Good luck.

Comment: But I need to change a shape color, so I can't use the background attribute because it will remove the drawable that I use. The colorcode is already saved but I just need to use it for a drawable color